# Converting monads

Tags: haskell, monads

Lets say I have function

```
(>>*=) :: (Show e') => Either e' a -> (a -> Either e b) -> Either e b
```

which is converting errors of different types in clean streamlined functions. I am pretty happy about this.

BUT

Could there possibly be function `<*-` that would do similar job insted of `<-` keyword, that it would not look too disturbing?

Comment: What does `(>>*=)` give you if its left argument is a `Left` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to write a function that you can use instead of the `<-` in do notation. The reason is that to the left of `<-`, there is a pattern, but functions take values. But maybe you can write a function

```
foo :: (Show e') => Either e' a -> Either e a
```

that converts the error messages and then use it like this:

```
do  x <- foo $ code that creates e1 errors
    y <- foo $ code that creates e2 errors
```

While this is not as good as the `<*-` you're asking for, it should allow you to use do notation.

Comment: "It is not possible to write a function that you can use instead of the <- in do notation" Yes it is, see RebindableSyntax : http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html

Comment: @user2407038, not sure. Rebindable syntax would allow to desugar all uses of `<-` to the `>>*=` from the question. But I think the question is about sometimes using `<-` and sometimes using `<*-`.

Comment: Yes, it is small percentage of uses, I decided to use additional function which is more conservative solution

Answer (score 7):

Well, my answer is really the same as Toxaris' suggestion of a `foo :: Either e a -> Either e' a` function, but I'll try to motivate it a bit more.

A function like `foo` is what we call a [**monad morphism**](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/03/mmorph-100-monad-morphisms.html): a natural transformation from one monad into another one.  You can informally think of this as a function that sends any action in the source monad (irrespective of result type) to a "sensible" counterpart in the target monad.  (The "sensible" bit is where it gets mathy, so I'll skip those details...)

Monad morphisms are a more fundamental concept here than your suggested `>>*=` function for handling this sort of situation in Haskell.  Your `>>*=` is well-behaved if it's equivalent to the following:

```
(>>*=) :: Monad m => n a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
na >>*= k = morph na >>= k
    where 
      -- Must be a monad morphism:
      morph :: n a -> m a
      morph = ...
```

So it's best to factor your `>>*=` out into `>>=` and case-specific monad morphisms.  If you read the link from above, and [the tutorial for the `mmorph` library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html), you'll see examples of generic utility functions that use user-supplied monad morphisms to "edit" monad transformer stacks—for example, use a monad morphism `morph :: Error e a -> Error e' a` to convert `StateT s (ErrorT e IO) a` into `StateT s (ErrorT e' IO) a`.